# Unable to determine file creation time with perl on Windows/Cygwin

Tags: windows, perl, file, cygwin

I wrote this to find out the file creation time for a given file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::stat;

open (my $fh, '<', "abc.txt") or die "$!";
my $t = (stat($fh))[9];
print $t;
```

However, this does not work, and gives:

```
Use of uninitialized value $t in print at ./tests.plx line 9.
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here? Or this can't be done on perl (5.14.2) on Windows/Cygwin, and I must choose some alternative method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509576/how-do-i-get-a-files-last-modified-time-in-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stat` from `File::stat` will return `File::stat` object. Remove `use File::stat;` to get array or use `my $t = stat($fh); print $t->atime;`.