# get last modified date of file with strawberry perl on windows

Tags: windows, perl, batch-file, command-line

I need to get the info on the file for when it was last modified using a perl script
heres the relevant code:

```
#where $file equals "MyFile.txt"
$backslash = "\\";
$upTwoLayersHelper = "..$backslash..$backslash";
@fileInfo = qx(forfiles /M $file /P $upTwoLayersHelper /C "cmd /c echo @fdate @ftime");
```

qx is a function in perl that allows the execution of a system command and redirects the output to a variable

Ive already looked into using `stat` and it kept returning

```
Dec 31 of like 1960
```

so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509576/how-do-i-get-a-files-last-modified-time-in-perl) did not work for me :/

I used the variables `$backslash` and `$upTwoLayersHelper` to build 'safely' the path since windows likes to use \ rather than / and I tested to make sure that the variables interpolate within the qx(...here...) function call.

My problem is the only output I get is

```
ECHO is on.
```

when I print the `@fileInfo` variable

**BUT** when I run the same command within the qx(...) function call **outside** of perl, and just in batch from the command line as a command it **works** and returns the correct date information

what am I doing wrong in my perl script?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Did you try with the [file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) for modification time_ -- `$mod_days = -M $file` ?  Also, the module [Win32API::File::Time](http://search.cpan.org/~wyant/Win32API-File-Time-0.006/lib/Win32API/File/Time.pm) should help.

Comment: You do mention `stat`, but just in case: did you use `(stat $file)[9]` for `mtime`? (The one for `ctime` won't work as expected on Windows.)

Comment: To clarify -- the `-M` uses a `stat` call but what you say about trying it is strange.  The `stat` time-related fields are in seconds _since_ epoch, which _starts_ 1970.  How do you get a date "_like 1960_" from that? The `-M` returns time in days, far clearer to check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@fileInfo = qx(for %x in ($file) do echo %~tx);
```

perhaps?

The `cmd` command for such purposes is

```
for %x in (filename) do echo %~tx
```

(assign the filename to the metavariable `%x` , then `echo` that file's [modification] date)

where the `%` needs to be `%%` if executed within a batch rather than from the prompt.

`ECHO is on.` is characteristic of an `echo` statement with no argument.

I'm not sure what the `two directories` higher idea is, but if that is where your target file is located, you'd need to nett prefix `filename` with `..\..\`

Perhaps

```
qx(echo %* whatever)
```

where *whatever* is your proposed `cmd` command will yield what `cmd` receives after all the escape-character resolutions (`%*` means "all supplied arguments")